# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android

Estoy tratando de insertar programáticamente 3 vistas dentro de un LinearLayout horizontal! con cada click del boton "add + ", esos 3 componentes deberían aparecer por debajo de la primera terna que se creó, por ese motivo traté de que el LinearLayout horizontal este dentro de un LinearLvertical.

Este es el error que me aparece: "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." este error se produce por la siguiente línea de codigo de mi programa:

rootLayoutVertical.addView(rootLayoutHorizontal);

Les agradecería mucho si pudieran ayudarme con este inconveniente. Gracias!

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int id = 125;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button customBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customButton);

    customBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Agregar();
        }
    });
```

public void Agregar() {

```
    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrl);

    LinearLayout rootLayoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_vertical);

    LinearLayout rootLayoutHorizontal = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_horizontal);

    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
    rootLayoutHorizontal.addView(spinner);

    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
    rootLayoutHorizontal.addView(editText);

    CustomButton customButton = new CustomButton(this);
    customButton.setBtn("Custom Button"+ id);
    customButton.setId(id);
    rootLayoutHorizontal.addView(customButton);
```

rootLayoutVertical.addView(rootLayoutHorizontal); //Aquí me da un error
id++;
 }

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/lista_productos_ventas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Artículos"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cantidad_productos_ventas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:drawablePadding="0dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/customButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/borde_redondo"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas agregando una vista que ya existe en el layout. Tú, primero declaras el `layout_horizontal` en xml y despues vuelves a agregarlo programaticamente en la linea `rootLayoutVertical.addView(rootLayoutHorizontal);`.

Para poder agregar más layout horizontales sin que te de este error, debes crear un nuevo layout horizontal cada vez que crees las vistas.

En vez de obtener el mismo layout horizontal como lo estas haciendo:

```
public void Agregar() {

    // ...

    LinearLayout rootLayoutHorizontal = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_horizontal);

    // ...

    rootLayoutVertical.addView(rootLayoutHorizontal);
}
```

Debes crea uno nuevo cada vez que crees las vistas:

```
public void Agregar() {

    // ...

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rootLayoutHorizontalParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    LinearLayout rootLayoutHorizontal = new LinearLayout(this);
    rootLayoutHorizontal.setLayoutParams(horizontalLayoutParams);
    rootLayoutHorizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    rootLayoutHorizontal.setWeightSum(3);

    // ...

    rootLayoutVertical.addView(rootLayoutHorizontal);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta que eh creado 2 veces el mismo layout.

Answer (score 0):

por opinion personal a mi mas me gusta manejarlo por layout.xml para agregar mas item, asi me libero de estar creando componentes por código.

1.- Tenemos el componente que agrega

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button customBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customButton);

    customBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Agregar();
        }
    });
```

2.- Creo el Layout con tus item.xml

```
</LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/lista_productos_ventas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Artículos"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cantidad_productos_ventas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:drawablePadding="0dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/customButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/borde_redondo"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

3.- Luego tenemos tu main donde colocaremos los item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">  

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

4.- Por ultimo el método agregar() seria así:

```
//linearlayout donde agregas todos los item
LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_vertical);

//item
LinearLayout row;

LayoutInflater inflaterHeader = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

row = (LinearLayout) inflaterHeader.inflate(R.layout.item, table, false);
row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

//Edittext
EditText et = row.findViewById(R.id.cantidad_productos_ventas);
//Spinner
Spinner sp = row.findViewById(R.id.lista_productos_ventas);
//Button
Button btn = row.findViewById(R.id.customButton);
```

Tips: Ideal si manejas el setTag en los componentes para guardar los estados de los objetos o en una lista porque tener en cuenta que estas usando un ScrollView y cuando se deslice ese scrollview se perderan los otros estados.